# Error when checking input: expected lstm_1_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (5, 3)

Tags: python, keras, lstm, categorical-data

I have a task of predicting room occupancy(1,2) from 3 sensors using LSTM. See the image below for an example of this data:

[image: data]

```
import pandas as pd
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.array([
    [31, 3, 5],
    [32, 3, 5],
    [29, 0, 3],
    [31, 3, 4],
    [23, 2, 4],
    [22, 2, 4],
    [23, 1, 4], ])

y = np.array([
    [2],
    [2],
    [1],
    [2],
    [1],
    [1],
    [1], ])

x = x.reshape(7, 3, 1)

x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(x, y,test_size =0.2, random_state = 4)

model=Sequential() 
model.add(LSTM((1), activation='softmax', input_shape=x_train.shape,return_sequences=False))
```

I got an error here:

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>   ----> 1 model.add(LSTM((1), activation='softmax', input_shape=x_train.shape, return_sequences=False))
>
> ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/sequential.py
>   in add(self, layer)
>       163                     # and create the node connecting the current layer
>       164                     # to the input layer we just created.
>   --> 165                     layer(x)
>       166                     set_inputs = True
>       167             else:
>
> ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/layers/recurrent.py
>   in **call**(self, inputs, initial_state, constants, **kwargs)
>       530 
>       531         if initial_state is None and constants is None:
>   --> 532             return super(RNN, self).**call**(inputs, **kwargs)
>       533 
>       534         # If any of `initial_state` or `constants` are specified and are Keras
>
> ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py
>   in **call**(self, inputs, **kwargs)
>       412                 # Raise exceptions in case the input is not compatible
>       413                 # with the input_spec specified in the layer constructor.
>   --> 414                 self.assert_input_compatibility(inputs)
>       415 
>       416                 # Collect input shapes to build layer.
>
> ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py
>   in assert_input_compatibility(self, inputs)
>       309                                      self.name + ': expected ndim=' +
>       310                                      str(spec.ndim) + ', found ndim=' +
>   --> 311                                      str(K.ndim(x)))
>       312             if spec.max_ndim is not None:
>       313                 ndim = K.ndim(x)
>
> ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_1: expected
>   ndim=3, found ndim=4

Then I could not run the below few lines I have because of the error:

```
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=20, validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
```

Can anyone help me identify the problem? All data are categories converted into integers, is it reasonable to create the model in this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reshape your input like this:

```
x = x.reshape(x.shape[0], 1, x.shape[1])  # the 1 is the steps
```

And specify the input shape like this:

```
input_shape=(x.shape[1:])
```

So use these lines and it will work:

```
x = x.reshape(7, 1, 3)

model.add(LSTM((1), activation='softmax', input_shape=x_train.shape[1:],
    return_sequences=False))
```

Lastly, your activation function should be `sigmoid` if you have only two classes.

Comment: Hi @NicolasGervais, Thank you so much for your help. 
Below is the result for the last epoch. I am getting the accuracy as 0, Do you know why?

WARNING:tensorflow:From /Users/ /python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py:3066: to_int32 (from tensorflow.python.ops.math_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use tf.cast instead.
Train on 5 samples, validate on 2 samples
Epoch 20/20
5/5 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 2.3781 - acc: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 1.6813 - val_acc: 0.0000e+00